# RoR - Nested Attributes - Chain of Tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I understood the option:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for
```

When I need to manipulate 2 tables trough 1 form, or 1 controller I can use that.

Before I try something that I didn't find answear let me know if I will break something in rails philosophy.

I have a chain of tables in my database:

```
TableA
  has_many :TableB
end

TableB
  belongs_to :TableA
  has_many:TableC
end

TableC
  belongs_to :TableB
  has_many :TableD
end
```

Adn so on... It stops somewhere.

Let me try an scenario with 5 tables in this pattern. If I use the first table, in the context above it's that TableA, can I manipulate all 5 tables at the same time? I mean, at the same controller? Same form, using that nested attributes => A accepts B, B accepts C, and so on?
Am I wrong thinking that way?

Thanks, you've been so nice!

*pattern example: country has many states, states has many cities, cities has many...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that.  That could leave you with a very complicated form for your users though.

Comment: What should be the correct aproach in this case? Many forms, one for each table? I think that it would be boring. But, like you said, it's going to be a complex form and unfortunately i don't know how to build  multiple level nested objects. I can build just 1 level: tableA.build_tableB, or tableA.tableBs.build

Comment: That's a judgement call you will have to make as the designer.  Think of your users, what would make the most sense to your typical user?